# Why do I see a deleted remote branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-clone, git-pull

I have a remote repository and 2 clones.
I create a branch in one of the clones e.g. `test`. I do some work and 2 commits. I merge  to `master` branch and `push -u` the branch.
I do a `git pull` in the other clone.
I see both `master` and `test`.
In the first clone project I do:
`git origin :test` to delete `test` branch on remote repository.
`test` is deleted on remote repos.
I do `git branch -D test` and the `test` branch is deleted locally as well.
If I do `git branch -a` I get:

```
*master  
remotes/origin/master
```

Now in the second repository I do a `git pull`.
On the pull the local `test` seems to be deleted but `git` seems to "think" that the remote `test` branch still exist.
If I do `git branch -a` I get:

```
* master  
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master  
  remotes/origin/master  
  remotes/origin/test
```

Why does the deleted `test` branch appear as a remote branch?

Answer (score 67):

The default options for `git fetch` (and consequently `git pull`) do not prune deleted remote branches. I'm not sure what the logic behind this default is. In any case, to prune deleted remote branches, either fetch with

```
git fetch -p
```

or run

```
git remote prune [-n] <name>
```

explicitly. With the `-n` flag, it will report which branches will be pruned, but not actually prune them. See [git-fetch(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) and [git-remote(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) for more information.

Comment: But if the repository was not mine how would I know that I would need to `prune`?

Comment: You can run `git remote prune -n <name>` to get a list, but I've resorted to just always running `git fetch -p` every time that I fetch. I didn't realize there wasn't an option for it on `git pull` since I never use `git pull`.

Comment: How is it different from doing just `git branch -d` on local? I have a branch named "feature-test" in my local while it's been merged and deleted on the remote, now I did `git pull -p` but it's still there on my local repository. So pruning is not working?!

Comment: Thanks @PeterLundgren. This helped me!. Github Pull Request does make the workflow easier can lead to quite some remote and local disconnected branches if one is not carefull. The two commands `git prune` and `git fetch -p` are added to my toolkit.

Answer (score 15):

Try using this command `git remote prune origin`. The deleted branch should disappear. This should remove local references to remote branches.

Comment: Actually I was expecting `git` to prompt me to do this the same way it prompts to do a `git pull`. Why doesn't it prompt?I have seen it prompting but perhaps it was in a different use case?

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. I can't really say i have seen git prompt anything about that when doing a pull, so i'm guessing it was a different use case. Tried to push something to a deleted branch perhaps?