# Why does git list a deleted remote branch?

Tags: git, github

[Very similar to [Why do I see a deleted remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17128466/96588), but none of the solutions there worked.]

When [forking a repository](https://github.com/l0b0/fake-s3) you may get a branch which you don't want:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/merge-brad
```

[Deleting remote branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/96588) is a well understood task, so let's do that:

```
$ git push origin :merge-brad 
To git@github.com:l0b0/fake-s3.git
 - [deleted]         merge-brad
```

Is it still in the branch list? Yes indeed:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/merge-brad
```

[Deleting local references to dead branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17128466/96588) is also well known. Let's try the [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17128699/96588):

```
$ git fetch -p
From github.com:l0b0/fake-s3
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Nope:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/merge-brad
```

Alright, how about the second one:

```
$ git remote prune origin
```

Still nope:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/merge-brad
```

And the third:

```
$ git remote prune origin
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/merge-brad
```

The branch list in GitHub doesn't display `merge-brad` anymore, but the local copy refuses to acknowledge this, so now what? Is [my Git configuration](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/8d07493f838bace557fbf2eab8011d0bb3a8bf2f/.gitconfig) breaking this somehow?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.8.3
```

Comment: It probably *should* be pruned, but I wonder: what does `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` show?

Comment: Right on the money, @torek.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I'd applied a [configuration change to get upstream pull requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27775093/96588) without looking closely at the command:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/upstream/pr/*"
```

I had assumed that the result would be that pulls of *`upstream`* would retrieve pull requests, but of course this modifies *`origin`*.

**The fix:**

```
$ git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: You can have multiple `fetch` settings for each remote.  Prune gets squirrelly in some complex cases, though, when it doesn't realize there are multiple ways to acquire some remote-tracking branch (fixed in more recent Git versions).